# Need help reading data from ESP32 with Flutter blue

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

So hello I am currently trying to connect a ESP32 with my Flutter App i am already able to connect the device with the App but now I want to read the value im sending from the ESP32.I display all the available bluetooth devices on my Homepage and want to display the value from the ESP32 on my Temperature Page.

This is my Current Code

Home Page:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  get device => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Adds the Drawer to the homepage from Navigation
      drawer: const DrawerNav(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MAS'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange[900],
      ),
      body: GetBuilder<Bluetooth>(
        init: Bluetooth(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                    stream: controller.scanResults,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final data = snapshot.data![index];
                              return Card(
                                elevation: 2,
                                // Makes Card Pressable
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () => data.device.connect(),
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    tileColor: Colors.orange[900],
                                    title: Text(data.device.name),
                                    subtitle: Text(data.device.id.id),
                                    trailing: Text(data.rssi.toString()),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      } else {
                        return const Center(
                          child: Text("No Device Found"),
                        );
                      }
                    }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    // todo: Button Thinigi in App
                    onPressed: () => controller.scanDevices(),
                    child: const Text("Scan")),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Temperature Page:

```
class TempPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TempPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TempPage> createState() => _TempPageState();
}

class _TempPageState extends State<TempPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MAS'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange[900],
      ),
      drawer: const DrawerNav(),
    );
  }
}
```

I already tryied dicoverServices but it dosnt find Devices on my Temperature Page so idk.

```
List<BluetoothService> services = await device.discoverServices();
services.forEach((service) {
    // do something with service
});
```

And because im new to flutter i dont realy have an idea how i could maby save the value in on the Homepage and transfere it to my Temperature Page.

If someone has an idea pleas help and pleas keep in mind im new to all this.

Comment: It may need some information hardware specification and experimental setting. I also don't see which programming language is this.